# Problems with mdiChild forms

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, mdi, mdichild

I'm use DevExpress DXperience and I created an MDI application that contains MdiChild forms.

1) I set in the Program.cs file "DevExpress Dark Style" as the defaut skin and it worked, also for child forms, the only problem that the skin of the title bar doesn't change. I tried this code `Form.LookAndFeel = "DevExpress Dark Style";` but it gives me this error:

> Property or indexer 'LookAndFeel' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only.

The same problem when I choose to change the skin from `skinsRibbonPageGroup`.

2) When I run an MDI child form, it should show me a `ScrollBar` when I change its dimensions, but this doesn't happen.

[image]

Comment: please answer my questions i need them for my school's summer project, i got only 3 days left.

Comment: You might want to try contacting DevExpress or use their support tools (they have a SO style 'Ask a question' page), because not everyone here may be familiar with DevExpress controls to be able to answer your question within your time constraint. Hope you get it solved. Happy coding.

Comment: This is not a fixable problem. MDI child forms do not comply with visual styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved !

The first solution is DmitryG's answer.

```
DevExpress.Skins.SkinManager.EnableMdiFormSkins();
```

For the second solution I contacted DevExpress Support Center and they told me that This behavior is caused by the fact that my ChildForm instances do not display scrollbars automatically, and to avoid this, simply to set the AutoScroll property to the true value for a ChildForm instance.

```
this.AutoScroll = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You should use the [SkinManager.EnableMdiFormSkins](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressSkinsSkinManager_EnableMdiFormSkinstopic) method to enables the title bar skinning feature for MDI child XtraForms.

Related articles:

1. [Skins](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2399)
2. [LookAndFeel](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2397)

2) It's difficult to determine the cause of the second issue due to the lack of information. I recommend you [report the issue](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Create) with a scrollbars directly to the DevExpress Support Center with a small sample project illustrating the problem.